# alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Can't locate revision identified by 'f1942fde9843'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

This happens when I do `flask db migrate` on my production PostgreSQL database.

Locally, migrate works fine (also PostgreSQL). I'm not sure what's wrong.

Some info: `f1942fde9843` is not in my `migrations/versions`. I'm not sure why it's looking for that. But I assume it must be important.

What do I do?

I'd rather not delete anything in production if I don't have to

Answer (score 0):

when you do a migration in a different branch than your original, you'll have missing migrations. to fix, you need to change alembic_version.version_num in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your DB. Delete the alembic table.  Then run:-

```
alembic upgrade head
```